# What's the best way to handle dates and times in PHP prior to 5.3?

Tags: php, php-5.2

Well, found out that I built a relatively large program built on top of DateTime, only to find most of what I used there got added in PHP 5.3. The server I have to deploy to does not run 5.3. (And it's a Ubuntu Hardy (8.04) box which doesn't have a 5.3 package in the main repo, and I'm not allowed to install anything not in the main repos on that box...)

1. Is there some way to get a copy of the [date and time function reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) as was current for 5.2.4?
2. What is the best way to pass dates around? `int`s containing unix epoch times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing data around, I prefer to use unix timestamps. If you have a different representation, you can use strtotime() to convert it.

There are a few functions that come in handy when working with dates & times. it looks like a lot of what is done w/ the DateTime object can be handled with some combinations of these methods:

- [date](http://php.net/date)
- [time](http://php.net/time)
- [mktime](http://php.net/mktime)
- [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

also, just a clarification on your terminology, the *unix epoch* is the moment all *unix timestamps* count from, which is midnight, Dec 31, 1969.

Comment: What type should I generally use to pass dates and times around though?

Comment: @Billy, realized I didn't read the question carefully, updated my answer.

Comment: It was kind of poorly written. I've edited it a bit :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Always using unix timestamps as int for date/time no matter of mysql version.

Comment: What does MySQL have to do with my question? And if you're in PHP 5.3, why not use the DateTime object?

Comment: Oops.. sorry, I wasn't slept for more then a day when I read your question and now I see that I read Mysql instead PHP :))

Comment: But anyway:), I still prefer unix timestamps for working with date/time, and just using date() for displaying it when needed.

Comment: DateTime uses unix timestamps internally anyway. It just additionally hangs methods off the value.